# Stack Exchange API - What does "site_state" mean?

Tags: support, api, sites

The [/sites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) route can return `site_state`.

What does `site state` stand for and which values can it have?

The values I found:

- normal
- linked_meta
- open_beta

Comment: See also the FAQ [How the /sites method is meant to be used](https://stackapps.com/q/1226/34061)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the [lifecycle of a Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/295232); most new sites start as private betas, become public betas and eventually graduate to a regular site.

There's also a value `closed_beta`, as documented [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site).

- `normal`: this is the default state. Beta sites end up here after they've graduated, before they get a design but *not* upon [losing the beta label](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/295232) because of their age. [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) is also considered a normal site, presumably because it's not linked. **Examples:** [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/), [Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/)
- `open_beta`: all sites which are in [public beta](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta) but haven't graudated. **Examples:** [Chess Stack Exchange](https://chess.stackexchange.com/), [Lifehacks Stack Exchange](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/)
- `closed_beta`: sites which are in ['private beta'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63401/295232) (currently none), and [CS50 Stack Exchange](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) which is in public beta but retained its private beta privilege levels
- `linked_meta`: a 'per-site meta', which is linked to a main Stack Exchange site. **Examples:** [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), [Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/)